# Migrate from Flash AS3 to AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, air, migrate

I've been developing a project in AS3 but decided to switch to AIR instead, as I found out it's impossible to save files on user's hard drive without prompt appearing.  My question is, what changes do I have to expect? is the code written in same AS3 syntax/style? Did instantiating objects / drawing shapes / positioning system / stage   change in AIR?  thanks.

Comment: If you are just migrating code you should now have an issue at all. Classes should not be an issue. If you have MovieClips you will have issues. It all depends on if it is a pure AS3 project or not.

Comment: I do have movieclips but they are created from within code. if that's what you mean..

Comment: What I meant was MovieClip instances in an fla. Basic you can't really convert timeline code of MovieClip instances. If the MovieCLips are create via code then it should not be an issue. This also brings up something else you might want to know. The only reason to create a MovieClip via code is so you can control the frames in that timeline. If you don't need frame control then you should create a Sprite instead. MovieClips extend Sprite and just adds frame support. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is the same from a code perspective, except that the AIR SDK includes quite a number of new APIs that are less restrictive and geared toward application development since the deployment target is no longer a web browser.

If you can, you should take a day or 2 and read thru the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/index.html) so you will know what's available to you.  Make sure to select the most recent versions of AIR and Flash Player under `Packages and Class Filters:  Runtimes` so the docs are populated with what you need.

Comment: okay, here is a side question: I've created a blank Air project, and imported an .as file to it.  Am I able to use AIR APIs in this .as file?  Like filestream for example? Because when I open this .as file and try to declare new File() object, it doesn't autocomplete the object's name itself and neither does it add import to filestream class.

Comment: what do you mean by"and imported an .as file to it"?

Comment: exactly what it sounds like, added an import of the .as file.  never mind i solved it.